# How to write to stdin in golang?

Tags: go, command-line-interface, user-input, readline

This is my code

```golang
func InputRead() string {
         reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin);
         fmt.Print("> ");
         text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n');
         text = strings.Replace(text, "\n", "", -1);
}
```

I want to place some string in os.Stdin, how would I achieve that?
It should appear
`> HAHA` then my cursor should have ability to remove that HAHA similar to `<input>` with prefilled text in HTML.
In python3 its implemented like this

```py
def stdininput(prompt, text):
         def hook():
             readline.insert_text(text)
             readline.redisplay()
         readline.set_pre_input_hook(hook)
         result = input(prompt)
         readline.set_pre_input_hook()
         return result
import readline
print(stdininput('> ', 'haha'))
```

For those who find it hard to understand, I am just asking to put a certain text (the text that we type when asked for input and can delete it) without typing. Like if user is asked for input and I want to provide a default input so user dont have to type.

Comment: Do you want "interactive text editing in command-line" implemented in Go?

Comment: I dunno but quick googling for golang+readline brings [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/chzyer/readline). I can go on explaning what readline-like libraries do, and how, but it appears you performed, like, zero research on your part before asking your question. So, does that package solve your need?

Comment: Probably yes, but i am trying to figure out how do i put that, could you post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, no one answered. After going for all the functions for those long period at last I found a function from readline library as kostix said. So, here's the sample program.

```golang
root@kali-linux:/tmp# cat main.go 
package main

import "github.com/chzyer/readline"
import "fmt"

func main() {
        input, _ := readline.New("> ");
        defer input.Close();

        datax := "Hey niko my friend"; //GTA IV
        data2 := []byte(datax);
        input.WriteStdin(data2);

        value, _ := input.Readline()
        fmt.Println(value);
}
root@kali-linux:/tmp# go run main.go 
> Hey niko my friend
```